# Give an example of strict inequality in Fatou's Lemma

Tags: lebesgue-integral

The fatou's Lemma says

Let $ \left\{ f_n, n = 1,2,...\right\} $ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions. Then $$ \liminf \int f_n  \geq \int \liminf f_n$$

Some hint?

I think this [Showing that the Fatou's lemma inequality can be strict.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332476/showing-that-the-fatous-lemma-inequality-can-be-strict) would work, but I don't understand why $\liminf f_n=0$ in the example he gives.

Comment: Fix an $x$ and consider $\{f_n(x)\}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545215/why-is-there-inequality-in-fatous-lemma?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1/2]}(x)&n\ \text{odd}\\ \boldsymbol 1_{[1/2,1]}(x)&n\ \text{even}\end{cases}$$